# Will dynamic metadata persist for bridged assets transfered between Ethereum and Polygon?

Tags: nft, erc-721, polygon, bridge

Im exploring how I can use polygon for my existing eth nft 721 contracts.

From what I can gather once Eth contract is mapped to polygon you can then bridge your assets over. This seems simple. I know the polygon token is burned when transferred over to ETH and vice versa but does does the metadata persist when transferring over? For example, consider the following use case:

User transfer nft from Eth to polygon
Admin calls setTokenURI of User A's NFT in polygon
User transfers NFT back from polygon to Eth

What happens to the metadata? If it does not persist what are some solutions? One in mind is to use an api server for both eth and polygon but that sounds too centralized.